# Textbox: missing first character typed on the TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 text boxes to accept info but only one of them is need at the same time (One is for selection of the first letter and the other is for selection of any part of the name)

So I need to delete the text of the other textbox when the user start typing on the textbox

Something like this work:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    TextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub
```

But there's a problem, the first character the user type is not displayed, I think is because the first character typed is used to launch the event.

Example:

TextBox1.Text = "A"
when the user click on TextBox2 and type michael the "m" is lost

I don´t want to use the "GotFocus" event because a simple TAB pulsed to jump from TextBox1 to another control can delete the text on TextBox1 when the user stop on TextBox2, even if he don´t want to type anything there

**How can I manage this mistake?**

Comment: So you have an error in your code, but you show us only a single line of code. Very difficult to help you with so little context. Do you have other code that changes the content of TextBox1 and TextBox2? Or can you explain better what is expected to be in TextBox1 when you type michael in TextBo2?

Comment: No user is going to expect this behavior and you will go mad trying to divine when to execute and when not to.  A better thing might be to select the text on the Enter event - at least that has been seen before by users

Comment: @steve just 2 text boxes one with the event I posted. That's all you need to check the problem I described

Comment: @Plutonix Right!! Problem solved. That's the solution!! I don´t lost the first character anymore. How can I mark your suggestion as the answer?

Comment: @steve just 2 text boxes one with the event I posted. That's all you need to check the problem I described. TextBox1.Text = "A" when the user click on TextBox2 and type michael the "m" is lost. Imagine a user want to search all the names with "A" as the first letter, then he type "A" on the first Textbox 1 but then he change of mind and want to search "Michael", well, the user clic on TextBox2 ant typed "Michael" but the "M" is lost becuase is the event used to clean the Text 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right answer:

From @Plutonix

"No user is going to expect this behavior and you will go mad trying to divine when to execute and when not to. A better thing might be to select the text on the Enter event - at least that has been seen before by users"